# Did Kai Kostack provide an accurate representation of the NIST simulation of the 7 World Trade Center building collapse?

Tags: 9-11

[Kai Kostack made a widely-watched YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVE3YwRgU9k) looking at [a recent UAF 7 World Trade Center study](https://ine.uaf.edu/wtc7)'s results.

In it, he displayed the [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/) [simulation](https://www.nist.gov/topics/disaster-failure-studies/world-trade-center-disaster-study/disaster-and-failure-studies) for comparison.

> [image: From the video, this is supposedly the NIST simulation]
> Image purportedly from the NIST simulation.

Ignoring his conclusion about the UAF simulation, his "NIST simulation" looks nothing like the real collapse.

> [image: Comparison][image]
> Simulation compared to real footage

The diagrams I saw in the NIST report look unlike the video provided:

> [image: NIST NCSTAR 1-9 p.588]

Was the video attributed to the NIST simulation an accurate portrayal of the results of the NIST report?

Comment: Not having spent hours of my life staring at pictures of WT7 collapsing, I find the claim "it looks nothing like the real collapse" vague to the point of meaningless. It seems this has a bearing on answers, because whatever is "wrong" with this picture may be sourcable even if the specific image is not.

Comment: I did not downvote either. However it is still unclear to me exactly what the claim is, why it's notable, and why you're skeptical of that claim. Is it this? "Someone (who?) claims that the UAF simulation doesn't match the NIST simulation." This seems like a rather arcane claim by a random youtuber, unless you can explain the significance.

Comment: Edited the question to avoid the subjectivity (see IMSOP's comment) and to be clearer to avoid @LShaver's confusion.

Comment: @Oddthinking the comparison to the real collapse also seems to have nothing to do with this question? It should either be removed, or included at the bottom as aside.

Comment: @Oddthinking somehow, this is *so* much better. Thanks. I was originally unsure as to whether it would be confusing or off-topic if I mentioned Kostack by name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The video appears to be from the LSDYNA NIST Model of the WTC 7 collapse.

From [the NIST website itself](https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2008/11/nist-releases-final-wtc-7-investigation-report), we have the link to [this video](https://youtu.be/PK_iBYSqEsc?t=58), which I have linked to the time in which a very similar simulation appears.

The video is also available from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NIST_WTC_7_collapse_model_with_debris_impact_damage.ogv), where the entire video, in its parts, are available to view.  While the original sources from the bottom of the Wikimedia Commons page appear to now be down, they all link back to NIST websites.

[Youtuber Mick West](https://www.youtube.com/c/MickWest/about) appears to have the actual LSDYNA model in his Youtube video [Some Problems with the UAF/Hulsey/AE911Truth WTC7 Draft Report](https://youtu.be/7OClixCTdDw?t=375).  He even addresses the issue with the deformation seen in the LSDYNA model.

> You also see this deformation here, which you don't see in reality.  A lot of people point to that as being a problem, but really that's just kind of indicative of the complex nature, the chaotic nature essentially of simulations like this.  Once you've gone past the initial point, the actual outcome can vary quite a lot.

Comment: How would you even be able to tell from looking at it, unless you had built the simulation? The simulation is not the images -- it's the math and equations behind them that can be visually presented in myriad ways.

Comment: The simulation in the NIST video does not display for long enough to show the substantial distortion mentioned in this question. So it's really hard to tell. Moreover, it seems very strange for the Youtuber to make such a mistake.

Comment: Because all youtubers are professional experts in the fields they youtube about and *never* make common amateur mistakes and then spend 30 minutes howling about how they've accidentally discovered something the 'deep state' has tried to keep hidden?

Comment: @Shadur This does not fit well with the context of the question. The guy involved is **not** a truther.

Comment: @Abdullah People arguing in good faith, even for their own position, can still make mistakes. Though perhaps the haranguing about the 'deep state' was uncalled for in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Kai Kostack [made a mistake.](https://www.metabunk.org/threads/debunked-nist-computer-simulation-of-building-7-collapse-is-inaccurate.11977/)

The simulation he used is the case without impact damage.

[image]

Whereas what he *should* have used is the NIST simulation with impact damage.

[image]